# error C2955: 'CELL' : use of class template requires template argument list C++ Stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stack

I am creating a custom stack to use with a old class that used the stack library.

Upon compiling I get the following error:

error C2955: 'CELL' : use of class template requires template argument list C++ Stack

It compiled with the .h file included up until I changed the stack (c++ library) to my_Stack (custom stack)

The code for the h is as followed

```
#ifndef generic_stack_H
#define generic_stack_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**************************************************************************
                        Structure CELL has two fields.
------------------     ------------------
| element | next | ->  | element | next |
------------------     ------------------
**************************************************************************/
template <class T>
struct CELL { T element; struct CELL *next; };

/**************************************************************************
                                Class STACK.
**************************************************************************/
template <class T>
class my_STACK
{
private:    CELL *topCellPtr;
public:
    //----------------------------Constructor-----------------------------
    my_STACK()    {topCellPtr = NULL;}
    //--------------------------Member functions--------------------------
void push(T e)
{
    struct CELL *cP;

    cP = new CELL;
    cP->element = e;
    cP->next = NULL;
    if(topCellPtr != NULL)   
        cP->next = topCellPtr;
    topCellPtr = cP;

}

void pop()
{
    struct CELL *cP;

    if(topCellPtr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Trying to pop an empty stack." << endl;
        return;
    }
    cP = topCellPtr;
    topCellPtr = topCellPtr->next;       
}

bool empty() {

    bool check false;

    struct CELL *cP;

    if(topCellPtr == NULL)
    {

       check = true;

    }

   return true;

}


T top()    {return topCellPtr->element;}

void print()
{
    struct CELL *cP = topCellPtr;

    cout << "Stack (top = left): ";
    while (cP != NULL)
    {
        cout << cP->element << " -> ";
        cP = cP->next;
    }
    cout << endl;       
}   

int Count_Occurences (int e) {

    int count = 0;

    struct CELL *cP = topCellPtr;

    while(cP != NULL) {

        if(cP->element == e) {

            count++;

        }//end if

        cP = cP->next;

    }//end while

    return count;

}

void Reverse_Stack() {

struct CELL *nP = NULL;

struct CELL *newtopCellPtr = nP;

while(topCellPtr != NULL) {

    int n = this->top();

    this->pop();

    nP = new CELL;
    nP->element = n;
    nP->next = NULL;

    if(newtopCellPtr != NULL) {

        nP->next = newtopCellPtr;

    }

    newtopCellPtr = nP;

}//end while

topCellPtr = newtopCellPtr;

}

int nth(int index) {

    struct CELL *cP = topCellPtr;

    for(int i=1; i < index; i++) {

        cP = cP->next;

    }//end for

    return cP->element;

}

void Append (my_STACK anotherStack) {

    anotherStack.Reverse_Stack();

    while(anotherStack.topCellPtr != NULL) {

        this->push(anotherStack.top());

        anotherStack.pop();

    }//

end while

    }

};

#endif
```

My main function is as followed:

```
#include <iostream> /*input output stream...
                     print on screen... keyboard input*/

//#include <stack>    //stack implementaiton

#include <ctype.h>

#include <string>

#include "generic_stack.h"

using namespace std;/*instead of specifically typing
                    std::cout we can simply write cout
                    this package also includes stack
                    container*/

enum state {FRESH, ID, NUM, ICT, LESS, GREATER, LESSDASH, PLUS, MINUS, ERR};

void reverse(my_STACK<char> &s) {

    my_STACK<char> s2;

    while(!s.empty()) {

        s2.push(s.top());

        s.pop();

    }

    s = s2;

}

void Reverse_Stack_Stack(my_STACK< my_STACK<char> > &s) {

    my_STACK< my_STACK<char> > s2;

    while(!s.empty()) {

        s2.push(s.top());

        s.pop();

    }

    s = s2;

}


void newLine(my_STACK<char> &P , state &current_state) {

    current_state = FRESH;

    while(!P.empty()) {

        P.pop();

    }

}

bool isToken(state s) {

    if(s == FRESH) {

        return false;

    } else if (s == ERR) {

        return false;

    } else {

        return true;

    }

}

bool canPush(char s , state current_state) {

    if(current_state == FRESH) {

        return true;

    } else

        if(current_state == NUM) {

            if(isdigit(s)) {

                return true;

            } else { 

                return false;

            }

    } else

        if(current_state == ID) {

            if(isalpha(s)) {

                return true;

            } else {

                return false;

            }

        } else

            if(current_state == LESSDASH) {

        if(s == '>') {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }/*end lessdash*/ else

    if(current_state == LESS) {

        if(s == '=' || s == '-' || s == '>') {

            return true;

        } else { 

            return false;

        }

    }/*end less */ else

    if(current_state == GREATER) {

        if(s == '=') {

            return true;

        } else { 

            return false;

        }

    }/*end greater*/ else

    if(current_state == PLUS) {

        if(s == '+') {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }/*end plus*/ else 

        if(current_state == MINUS) {

        if(s == '>') {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

}/*end minus */ else {      

        return false;

        }

}

state nextState(state current_state, char c) {

        if(current_state == LESS && c == '-') {

            return LESSDASH;

        } else 

            if(c == '<') {

    return LESS;

    } else

    if(c == '>') {

    return GREATER;

    } else

    if(c == '+') {

    return PLUS;

    } else

    if(c == '-') {

    return MINUS;

    } else

    if(isalpha(c) || c == '_') {

    return ID;

    } else

    if(isdigit(c)) {

    return NUM;

    } else

    if(c == '~' || c == '&' || c == '^' || c == '*' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c == ':' || c == ',' || c == '=') {

        return ICT;

    }  else {

            return ERR;

        }

}

my_STACK< my_STACK<char> > maxMunch(my_STACK<char> S) {

    my_STACK<char> P;

    my_STACK< my_STACK<char> > T;

    state current_state = FRESH;

    while(!S.empty()) {

        while(S.top() == ' ' || S.top() == '\t' || S.top() == '\r' || S.top() == '\n') {

            S.pop();

            if(!P.empty()) {

                T.push(P);

                while(!P.empty()) {

                    P.pop();

                }

            }

            current_state = FRESH;

        }//end second loop

        if(canPush(S.top() , current_state)) {

            P.push(S.top());

            current_state = nextState(current_state, S.top());

            S.pop();

        } else {

            if(isToken(current_state)/*P is a valid token*/) {

                 T.push(P);

                 newLine(P , current_state);

             } else {

                cout << "Tokenizing Error";

                 newLine(P , current_state);

             }//end else

        }

    }//end loop


    T.push(P);


     if(S.empty()) {

            return T;//returns the tokens

        }

}

/**************************************************************************
Takes a string s and a stack theStack by refernce. Breaks the stirng s into
char data types and pushes them into the stack theStack.
***************************************************************************/
void Break_Up_Into_Stack(string s, my_STACK<char> &theStack)
{
    while (!theStack.empty())   {theStack.pop();} // empty the stack before use.

    for ( int pos = s.length() - 1; pos >= 0; pos--)
        theStack.push(s.at(pos));

}

/**************************************************************************
Takes a stack of chars s by value. Prints the stack on screen.
***************************************************************************/
void Print_Stack_Of_Char (my_STACK<char> s)
{
    cout << "-----top of stack: -----" << endl;
    while (!s.empty())  {cout << s.top(); s.pop();}
    cout << endl;
    cout << "---Bottom of stack: ----" << endl << endl;
}

void printMunch (my_STACK< my_STACK<char>> s)
{

    while (!s.empty())  {

       Print_Stack_Of_Char (s.top());

        cout << "" << endl; 

        s.pop();

    }

}

void Print_Tokens (my_STACK<my_STACK<char> > s)
{
    int count = 1;
    Reverse_Stack_Stack(s);
    while (s.empty() == false)
{
    cout << count << ". ";
    reverse (s.top());
    while (s.top().empty() == false)
    {
    cout << s.top().top();
    s.top().pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
    count++;
    s.pop();
    }
}

int main() //main function
{
//state A = GREATER;
 //char c = '-';
 //cout << canPush(c, A) << endl;
        string inputString;
    my_STACK<char> charStack;

    cout << "Enter the string: ";
    getline(cin, inputString);

    string testString1 = "83 - 8 * [aVar - (2 + 1)] / aVar2";
    string testString2 = "amountOfWork <= 1";

    Break_Up_Into_Stack(inputString, charStack);

    //Print_Stack_Of_Char(charStack);

    //reverse(charStack);

    my_STACK <my_STACK<char> > Final;

    Final = maxMunch(charStack);

    Print_Tokens(Final);

    //printMunch(Final);
    char inp;
    cin>>inp;

}
```

I have no idea what the error could be, I have tried numerous things and it doesn't work. the program worked with the original stack but I need to implement the custom stack.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is what the compiler outputs:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: project_7, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_7\project_7\generic_stack.h(29): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'template'
1>c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_7\project_7\main.cpp(23): error C2039: 'empty' : is not a member of 'my_STACK<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=char
1>          ]
1>c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project_7\project_7\main.cpp(23): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The full error is in the "Output" window, The "error" window only has summaries.  Since you don't have the full error, nor tell us what line has the error, we're going to have to make guesses, and we might not be able to help you.

Comment: `CELL *topCellPtr;` should be `CELL<T> *topCellPtr;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class T>
struct CELL { T element; struct CELL *next; };

template <class T>
class my_STACK
{
private:    CELL *topCellPtr;
```

You declare `CELL` as a template that the compiler can make classes with.  It is important to note that `CELL` is not technically a class.  Therefore you can't have a pointer to it.  You have to tell `my_STACK` what class `topCellPtr` points at, so that line should be:

```
private:    CELL<T> *topCellPtr;
```

You will probably have to do this throughout all of `my_STACK`'s code.

Comment: My screen says you beat me by 4 seconds, but I typed a lot more :P

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specialize your use of `CELL` inside the stack class:

```
private:    CELL *topCellPtr;
```

should be

```
private:    CELL<T> *topCellPtr;
```

This is just one place, there are numerous others.